# Error when updating user service presence status with lightning:omniToolkitAPI

Tags: aura, omnichannel

I am facing an issue with omnichannel status changing in aura component with **lightning:omniToolkitAPI** . When calling the method I make the console.log to check if Id is presented and it is there right before the call of `omniAPI.setServicePresenceStatus({statusId: statusId})`.

```
The issue is Failed to change status. Unable to process: invalid ServicePresenceStatus Id.
```

I have checked the Id and it is correct. User profile has access to the selected status.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After some painful time of digging, I have found a reason to this issue.

It seems like omniToolkitAPI in aura components support only 15-digits Id values, so after trimming the 18-digit Id to 15-digit Id everything has worked as expected.

Could not find any mention of this limitation in the salesforce documentation though.